Architecture of a NextJs monorepo with very similar apps
I would like to set a NextJs monorepo project using the app router, which consist in a lot of web apps very similar. Potentially with Turborepo. I use Vercel to host all nextjs app. (maybe not the most cost effective way, but this is not the subject)
The frontend apps (between 10 and 100) are very very similar as said, and half of them would only differ from data in their own database, without any custom component or other pages. So the root directory as specified in Vercel project of that kind of app would just be the generic app.
The other half needs to be enhanced with custom components (replace generic header or generic button by custom ones for example) AND new pages or api endpoints can be added.
I thought about a structure like :
├── Apps
│   ├── GenericApp
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── page1
│   │   │   ├── page2
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   └── api
│   │   │       ├── route1
│   │   │       ├── route2
│   │   │       └── ...
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   ├── header
│   │   │   ├── card
│   │   │   ├── button
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── FirstApp
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   └── page3
│   │   └── components
│   │       └── button
│   └── SecondApp
│       └── components
│           └── header
└── ...

In this example, for first app, a page3 would be added to the app and generic button would be replaced by specific one for FirstApp.
You can see that FirstApp and SecondApp do not contain necessary files to be real nextjs apps, just the parts specific to that app. So I thought to copy in deployment command all generic files of GenericApp into specific Apps that do not exists in them, and launch yarn dev or yarn build after that.
Another requirement is that if some modification is done in generic app, all projects are redeployed. And if only a custom component for example of FirstApp is edited, only FirstApp project would be redeployed.
Do you think that approach could work and if it is scalable ?
Thanks a lot!
